# Get session from another domaine

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have a wordpress web site and Phalcon web application on another server. When I'm logged on my web application I have a session. When I'm back on wordpress I want to check if there is a session on my web application and if it's true I'll log the user on wordpress too.

So I thought I'll create a web service in my web application and it will called by wordpress. In this web service I'll check if the session exists and return the email user to log wordpress side.

But I have a problem because when I use the web service with wordpress, the session does not exist. But when I enter the URL via the browser, it works.

Could you help me to do that ?

**Wordpress side**

```
add_action( 'init', 'process_post' );

function process_post() {

$url = 'http://exemple.com/webapp/controller/logged';

$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'timeout' => 45,
        'redirection' => 5,
        'httpversion' => '1.0',
        'blocking' => true,
        'headers' => array(),
        'body' => array( 'from' => 'authentication' ),
        'cookies' => array()
    )
);

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
   echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
   echo 'Response:<pre>';
   print_r( $response );
   echo '</pre>';
}

}
```

**Phalcon Web application web service**

```
public function loggedAction(){
    $this->view->disable();
    $auth = $this->session->get('my_session');

    if($auth){
        $jsonResponse = array('authorization' => 'OK');
        return $this->jsonBuilder($jsonResponse);
    }
}
```

This is not the whole code phalcon side but this code can be good just for testing

Comment: The request sent to your webservice is not issued by the browser, but by the server your Wordpress runs on. The session is not tied to the server, but to the user's browser, so obviously it does not exist.

Comment: So this is impossible to do that with a session ? How can I do that ?

Comment: At least the way you are attempting at the moment definitely won't work, no.  If both applications ran on the same domain, that would get a little easier, but you would still have to merge the session handling of both systems. What you are looking for is usually called "Single Sign On" and it is mostly not an easy problem to solve. I don't know Phalcon, so I can't be sure, but you will probably not find an easy or quick solution to this. And sadly, I also believe that this is not the right place to go into detail about this. It's too complex.

Comment: Ok thanks. So SSO is the best option. I'll try to implement later.